# I want to display the names and profile pic of my followers in a template..i am only able to display the names of followers.please suggest

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Here is my UserProfile models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import question
from question.models import Tag

# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES=(
        ('M','Male'),
        ('F','Female'),
    )
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,blank=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    age=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    pic=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    follow_tags=models.ManyToManyField("question.Tag"   )
    bio=models.TextField(blank=True)
    mobile=models.CharField(max_length=12,unique=True,default='')
    college=models.CharField(max_length=1024,default="not specified ")
    address=models.TextField(default="not specified")
    followers=models.ManyToManyField('auth.User',related_name='followers',blank=True)
    following=models.ManyToManyField('auth.User',related_name='following',blank=True)
    #profile_pic=models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics/',blank=True)
    User.profile=property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Here is my function to add followers

```
def follow(request, userprofile_id=1):
    x = UserProfile.objects.get(id=userprofile_id)
    p=request.user
    t=x.user.id
    x.followers.add(p)
    x.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/account/profile/get/%s' %t)
```

This is my view to show followers

```
def show_followers(request,userprofile_id=1):
    return render(request,'show_followers.html',
              {'userprofile':UserProfile.objects.get(id=userprofile_id)}
             )
```

Finally this is show_followers template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap_toolkit %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
{% if userprofile.pic %}
<p><img src="{{userprofile.pic.url}}" width="150" height="150" class="img-circle"/></p>
{% endif %}
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
<h1>{{userprofile.name}}</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<h5>Answers</h5>
<h5>Questions</h5>
<h5>Followers | {{userprofile.followers.count}}</h5>
<h5>Following | </h5>
</div>
<p>{{userprofile.followers.count}} Followers</p>
<h4>{% for c in userprofile.followers.all %}
<div class="col-md-4">
<a href="/account/profile/get/{{c.id}}">{{c}}</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

looping in userprofile.followers.all could only display the name of the followers..i have to display every details linked with followers..Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You don't seem to be even trying to call the attributes on `c`.

Comment: the attribute c is giving only the username of the followers..i tried trying c.- but that's not working

Comment: I still don't understand. What is `c.` supposed to mean? `c` is an instance of auth.User, it has all the attributes of that model, and you access those like you would any other property - as you are *already* doing with `c.id`.

Comment: sir this model UserProfile has field user that has a OneToOne relationship with "auth.user" ..since auth.user have only limited fields like email,username and all..so i linked a profile model to every auth user...now i want to access the profile information of that auth.user who is following some other user...yes you right c is an instance of auth.User...but auth.User doesn't have attributes like profile pic,bio and other details...these details are linked with profile model..please suggest me a solution for doing this..i am a beginner in djnago

Comment: So this question just boils down to how to get to a UserProfile given a User? Then you should have asked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a User, you can get to the UserProfile via the `userprofile` accessor.

```
 {{ c.userprofile.age }}
```